# What does 'play' mean in the context of Courser of Kruphix?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

Definition of 'play' in mtg for spells indicates it is synonym of cast. On the other hand on [Courser of Kruphix](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Courser%20of%20Kruphix) it seems to be constant ability. What does 'play' mean in Magic?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Courser of Kruphix uses the word "play" in two different ways. When it says

> Play with the top card of your library revealed.

It means that you play **the game** with the top card of your library revealed. That ability is a static ability, so it is in effect for as long as the Courser of Kruphix is on the battlefield.

On the other hand, when it says

> You may play the top card of your library if it's a land card.

That simply means that you can play lands on top of your library like your are normally able to do from your hand.

Comment: You should probably mention the thing where 'play' and 'cast' don't mean the same thing.

Comment: I don't see why it's relevant here. Courser of Kruphix says that you can play lands from the top of your library. This is the standard wording for the special action that you can perform once per turn to put a single land into play while the stack is empty during your main phase. Anything involving spells is irrelevant.

Comment: The asker thinks casting and playing are analogous and is confused why some cards say 'cast' but Courser says 'play'. That's all. This is a good answer even without that and I've already upvoted it, I just think this would be beneficial to mention.

Comment: The way I read the question, I think the asker's actual point of confusion was the distinction I explained in my answer. If they say that is not the case, I'll change my answer. Until then, I see no reason to change it.

Comment: fair enough then

Comment: That exactly answered my question! Thank you all! Great community!

Comment: I too think the distinction between cast and play would be important to note, since the question mentions that they appear to be synonymous.

Comment: The asker's confusion is about the difference between "play" as it's used in the first ability and "play" as in "play a card", which are completely separate things. In my opinion, adding in notes about the difference between casting spells and playing lands would be superfluous and would only distract from the distinction I'm trying to explain. If you want an answer that explains that difference, you are free to add your own, or upvote one of the existing answers that does so.

Comment: I think it deserves a special mention that the usual restrictions to playing lands still apply. Most notably, you can only play 1 land per turn, regardless of whether you played it from hand or from your library via Courser.

Comment: Guys, actually all the things you mention I found online, my confusion was because Courser say play (something) instead of play the game as murga explained. Then I checked what play meant :)

Answer (score 7):

Play means two different things here. (It used to mean a lot more things; see the footnote at the end.)

The first ability's instruction to play with the top card of your library revealed just means that whilst you're playing the game, you should have the top card of your library revealed.

In the second ability ("You may play the top card ..."), "playing" a card is *close* to casting, but "playing" is a broader term that refers to something else *in addition* to casting. Playing a card refers to one of two things:

- cast a card as a spell<sup>[1](https://yawgatog.com/resources/magic-rules/#rule-601-1-a)</sup>, or
- put a land onto the battlefield<sup>[2](https://yawgatog.com/resources/magic-rules/#rule-305-1)</sup>, which doesn't use the stack or count as casting.

In particular, that means *lands cannot be cast.* They can only be *played.* So, [Courser of Kruphix](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Courser%20of%20Kruphix) *has* to use the verb "play", as must anything that lets you put a land on the battlefield.

Compare this to [Daxos of Meletis](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Daxos%20of%20Meletis), who allows you to *cast* exiled cards — which means you can cast creatures, sorceries, instants, artifacts, and enchantments exiled by Daxos, *but not lands.*

---

*Footnote:* In cards printed before the Magic 2010 core set (released 2009), "play" meant other things, such as activating an ability, and the "cast" verb wasn't a thing. "Play" was pretty overloaded and confusing, so [they made those usages obsolete in 2010](https://web.archive.org/web/20160120014846/http://archive.wizards.com/Magic/magazine/article.aspx?x=mtg/daily/feature/42a) and added new concepts such as "casting" a spell and "activating" an ability.

Answer (score 1):

When playing with Courser of Kruphix you will play with the top card of your library revealed (first ability).

If that revealed card happens to be a land you can then play it as if it was in your hand (can still only play the normal amount of lands each turn and you can only use it when you can normally play a land). This will gives you a couple of benefits.  First it lets you play a land if you don't have one in your hand (or chose not to play a land from your hand). Second it lets you get a land card out of the deck faster so you can get to more valuable cards. Third you get to gain life from the third ability.

So in short for this card "play" is treated like playing any other land on your turn

Here is the rulings on this card

http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=courser+of+kruphix

Comment: Yes, thank you, but some people keep reavealing their cards as long as courser is on battlefield, not only when they play (cast) it. Is it correct?

Comment: @xio As long as it is in play the top card of the deck will be revealed. It says to play with the top card of your library revealed.

Comment: Joe, just to make sure - when I checked definition of play in mtg it said it means to cast (except for lands). You cast a spell only once. Why in case of courser it means something else? Sorry if this is obvious/naive question.

Comment: @xio Look at dopperlgreener's answer for a better explanation.

Comment: Doppelganger answered a different question, my issue is consistence of magic keywords. To add to my confusion - the definition of 'play' from the rules: http://www.mtgsalvation.com/forums/magic-fundamentals/magic-rulings/magic-rulings-archives/291359-definition-of-play

Comment: @xio you will want to reread that. `701.11b To play a card means to play that card as a land or to cast that card as a spell, whichever is
appropriate.` Reading that it shows you have two options, play the card as a land or cast that card as a spell. If you look closer at the post it is only focusing on the casting part and not the playing land part. Also its always better to get the rules from the official site. http://media.wizards.com/images/magic/tcg/resources/rules/MagicCompRules_20140601.pdf

Comment: I don't mean to contradict for the sake of the discussion, I'm trying to figure this out. Is there any paragraph in the rules that suggests that to play a creature means to have it on the battlefield? Play is an action after all, not a status of the card...

Comment: @xio I think you need to take a look at the rules and the card you are asking about as all that is involved is the ability to play a land not a spell of any type from the top of your deck.

Comment: "Play with the top card of your library revealed" - ok simple: I play the courser. I reveal the card. Where does it say I reveal again next turn? :)

Comment: @xio the next turn if your top card is not revealed are you following the wording on the card or doing the opposite?

Comment: @xio I think that my answer can resolve your confusion.

Comment: Yes, Murgatroid, now I understand! Play the game, not play the card. Thanks guys!